# Unable to Retrieve Data Fro Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to retrieve data from Firebase in the `List`. For that I have created an Activity for retrieving and a `Retrieving` class. When getting data from Firebase, the problem comes when I open the `Retrieve` activity by pressing a button. It opens for a while the moves back to the previous Activity...

I have used the same code in the another project and there is no issue in that. I am stuck...

here is my `Retrieve` Activity

```
public class RetrieveTourPlan extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView mylistView;
DatabaseReference db;
EditText search_edit_text;
List<ClassTourPlan> TourPlanList, totalreqSale, TouredArea, TouredCity;
String searchtext;
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrieve_tour_plan);


    mylistView = findViewById(R.id.mylisttourplan);
    search_edit_text= findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    TourPlanList = new ArrayList<>();
    totalreqSale = new ArrayList<>();
    TouredArea = new ArrayList<>();
    TouredCity = new ArrayList<>();

    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DbTourPlan");
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            TourPlanList.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                ClassTourPlan classTourPlan=snapshot.getValue(ClassTourPlan.class);
                TourPlanList.add(classTourPlan);
            }

            TourPlanListClass adapter = new TourPlanListClass(RetrieveTourPlan.this, TourPlanList);
            mylistView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

}
}
```

Class with this

```
public class TourPlanListClass extends ArrayAdapter<ClassTourPlan> {
private Activity context;
int position;
List<ClassTourPlan> tourPlanList;

public TourPlanListClass(Activity context,List<ClassTourPlan> tourPlanList){
    super(context,R.layout.mylistlayout,tourPlanList);
    this.context=context;
    this.tourPlanList=tourPlanList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater= context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItems= inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylistlayout,null,true);

    TextView textTourId=listViewItems.findViewById(R.id.tvtourid);
    TextView textViewTotalReqSale=listViewItems.findViewById(R.id.tvtotalreqsale);
    TextView textViewTouredArea=listViewItems.findViewById(R.id.tvtouredarea);
    TextView textViewTouredCity=listViewItems.findViewById(R.id.tvtouredcity);



    ClassTourPlan strtingEndingPoint= tourPlanList.get(position);

    textTourId.setText(strtingEndingPoint.getClsTourId());
    textViewTotalReqSale.setText(strtingEndingPoint.getClstotalreqsale());
    textViewTouredArea.setText(strtingEndingPoint.getClstourarea());
    textViewTouredCity.setText(strtingEndingPoint.getClstourcity());

    return listViewItems;
}
}
```

I have erased this code from the `Retrieve` Activity, then no issue occurs

```
  for (DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                ClassTourPlan classTourPlan=snapshot.getValue(ClassTourPlan.class);
                TourPlanList.add(classTourPlan);
            }
```

Here are the Rules

```
    {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

The Logcat is showing nothing but

> 11-27 23:03:35.523
>   30191-30191/com.example.medicalrepresentative.application E/HAL: load:
>   id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc 11-27 23:03:35.583
>   30191-30264/com.example.medicalrepresentative.application E/HAL: load:
>   id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc 11-27 23:03:35.588
>   30191-30264/com.example.medicalrepresentative.application E/HAL: load:
>   id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc

Comment: The log output you shared seems unrelated to the problem you describe. Stack Overflow is a really inefficient interactive debugger, so it's best if you can run the app in a debugger locally, and get closer to the source of the problem that way. For example, if you put a breakpoint on the first line in `onDataChange` and run the app in the debugger, does that breakpoint ever get hit? If so, step through the method, and see if each line does what you expect it to do.

Comment: Also: **never** leave `onCancelled` empty as you're ignoring potential problems that way. The simplest implementation is `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`